# New lines are not continuing block comments, only in php

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

Say I type

```
/**
```

and hit return.  In a .cpp file, or a .js file, the cursor would continue adding `*`s for me.

```
/**
 *
```

But in a .php file, the cursor just moves to the next line.  It's very annoying because I'm trying to document our API, which completely lacks it at the moment.

Relevant output:

```
formatoptions=tcroq
```

I don't have anything in my vimrc that is specific to PHP.  I do have syntastic installed, but for some reason in php files, comment lines aren't even being grayed out as if they were comments.

Any ideas?  Is there a way I can find out what file is setting different settings?

Comment: See `:h format-comments` for more information.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer! You should [self-answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) this question.

Comment: You should write a self answer, summarising that SO thread.  Self-answers are a good measure of the fact that you found a solution to your question yourself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a very similar thread on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061321/incorrect-comments-set-for-php-in-vim

I did the following:

1. Checked that `filetype plugin on` came before `filetype indent on` in my `.vimrc`.  It did, so that wasn't the cause of the problem.
2. Added the following line to make vim register comment lines in php files:

   `au FileType php setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,:#`

   `au FileType php setlocal formatoptions+=cro`

I made mine match the rest of my files' format options, so I set it to `tcroq` instead.

I'm using Vim 7.4 on ArchLinux.

<strike>Oddly, this didn't set the colors of comments to be grayed out like my colorscheme specifies, but it does have the correct indention behavior.</strike>

Edit:  Last statement was because of missing `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: Regarding the comment color, are your comments inside de `<?php`  and  `?>` tags ? In my Vim it only highlights comments inside those tags.

Comment: Ah!  you're right.